# How to check if string contains another string (but may have other letters in between)?

Tags: c++, string, loops, for-loop, function-definition

To explain it better lets say I get two strings as an input and I compare if they match. However it would still count as a match if some letters are doubled

Input: "alex", "aaleex"
Output: true

Input: "saeed", "ssaaedd"
Output: false

Input: "leelee", "lleeelee"
Output: true

My C++ function

```
 bool isLongPressedName(string name, string typed) {
    
    if(name == typed) return true;
    
    size_t lenName = name.length();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < lenName; i){
        //tried to check if typed contains all letters from name
    }
       
    //so if contains all letters inside even if its bigger and contains 
    //long pressed letter return true

    return false

}`
```

It is an assignment from one of a popular sites so I can check solutions too in there but I hope someone here could help me understand it better. Because I got kind of stuck on my idea and started thinking its wrong approach anyway.

Comment: How would you do with a paper and a pen?

Comment: With your paper and pen, try looking for the _first_ character.  Then think about _where_ you are going to search for the next character.  Repeat.

Comment: This is a reasonable question to ask someone, but I am not certain "give me hints so I can solve this myself" is [on-topic for SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359449/16287).

Comment: You should think about your preconditions and then about what could happen in each iteration step. **1.** precondition: your correct string has to be equal or shorter than the string you compare to **2.** what will do in each iteration: in each iteration, you will move one char further in the string that might have duplications, until an invalid char appears, or you reach the end. In your reference string you might pause the movement to the next char if the current char and the next one are different (in case that the other string has duplications there)

Comment: @DrewDormann edited so its more reasonable then

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function parameters should have the constant referenced type `const std::string &` or the type `std::string_view`.

All what you need is the member function `find`.

The function `isLongPressedName` can look for example the following way as shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

bool isLongPressedName( const std::string &name, const std::string &typed )
{
    bool present = not ( typed.size() < name.size() );
    
    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0, pos = 0; present && i < name.size(); i++ )
    {
        pos = typed.find( name[i], pos );
        
        if ( ( present = pos  != std::string::npos ) ) ++pos;
    }
    
    return present;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isLongPressedName( "alex" , "aaleex" ) <<'\n';

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isLongPressedName( "saeed" , "ssaaedd" ) << '\n';

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isLongPressedName( "leelee", "lleeelee"  ) << '\n'; 

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
false
true
```

Or if the string `typed` shall not contain characters other than characters present in the string `name` then the function can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

bool isLongPressedName( const std::string &name, const std::string &typed )
{
    bool present = not ( typed.size() < name.size() );
    
    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0, pos = 0; present && i < name.size(); i++ )
    {
        if ( ( present = pos < typed.size() ) )
        {
            if ( i != 0 && name[i] != typed[pos] )
            {
                pos = typed.find_first_not_of( name[i - 1], pos );
            }
        
            if ( ( present = pos != std::string::npos && name[i] == typed[pos] ) )
            {
                ++pos;
            }
        }           
    }
    
    return present;
}


int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isLongPressedName( "alex" , "aaleex" ) <<'\n';

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isLongPressedName( "saeed" , "ssaaedd" ) << '\n';

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isLongPressedName( "leelee", "lleeelee"  ) << '\n'; 

    return 0;
}
```

Again the program output is

```
true
false
true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using sets here would be a better approach

```
bool isLongPressedName(string name, string typed) {
    set<char> s;
   
    for(auto i : typed) {
        s.insert(i);
    }    

    typed = "";
    for(auto j : s) {
        typed += j;
    }

    return (name == typed);
}
```

Comment: `std::set` doesn't handle duplicates, (as required in OP's example). and order should be important too.

Comment: hey @Jarod42, thanks for the edit recommendation. I get it what you are trying to say about the order of elements in the set, can you please describe if you know of any ways to insert elements into a set in a given order

Comment: [`std::includes`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes) of both [`std::multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) without order, else, no set usage